# I need to send get request via ajax, how do I use route that accepts a parameter

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have a table with rows, if I click on a row I need to fetch additional data via ajax request

I have this javascript code that listens on any id that matches categoryid patterns, my ids are like
categoryid1
categoryid2
etc

Problem here is that I need to dynamically get the id at the time of the click and then make get request, route requires the id for this

#### Routes

```
Route::get('test/{id}', ['as' => 'test', 'uses' => 'Controller@test']);
```

#### Ajax call

```
$('[id^=categoryid]').click(function(event) {
        var id = event.target.id.slice(10);        
        $.get("{{route('name', id)}}", function(data, status){
            console.log(data);
        });
```

How do I insert this id at the time of click? blade has already rendered the html code on the server side and will ask for an extra parameter to route function, first being the route name and second an id to send to the route.

Comment: Is it possible to modify the route (or write a new one) so it takes the id as a get or post parameter rather than a parameter in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding the id in laravel blade, bind it in JS

```
$('[id^=categoryid]').click(function(event) {
    var base_route = {{route('test')}}; // Get the base route without parameters
    var id = event.target.id.slice(10);        
    $.get(base_route+"/"+id, function(data, status){
        console.log(data);
    });
```